# Template Suggestion 403 pages

Tags: theming

The following implementation adds a template suggestion for page, in this case if you create a page--404.html.twig file in your theme, you'll be able to customize the page and works with Drupal 8.5.3

**MYTHEME.theme:**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_page_alter(&$suggestions, $variables, $hook) {
  /**
   * 404 template suggestion.
   */
  if (!is_null(Drupal::requestStack()->getCurrentRequest()->attributes->get('exception'))) {
    $status_code = Drupal::requestStack()->getCurrentRequest()->attributes->get('exception')->getStatusCode();
    switch ($status_code) {
      case 404: {
        $suggestions[] = 'page__' . (string) $status_code;
        break;
      }
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

[(code published by Israel Morales)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39139541/custom-404-template-file-in-drupal-8)

Can someone, please, adapt this code to the 403 Pages?

Comment: Isn't the answer right on the page you linked to? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43421614/295112

Comment: the answer is right but it only aplies to 404 pages, and I need the solution for the 403 pages

Comment: The answer I linked to specifically mentions system.403. Does that not work?

Comment: No, the If statment need to be changed: if (!is_null

Comment: Sorry I don’t understand. I believe I’m using the answer I linked to on another project and it works.

Comment: @HenriqueMoreira, if you don't find the 403 exception in the request, then you probably have a module installed handling 403s not using the base class HttpExceptionSubscriberBase.

Comment: I used the solution of the MYTHEME.theme approach (that only solves the 404 Pages) and not the solution of MYMODULE, because I  don’t know how to implement it. Can you help me with any tip on how to set up the solution via MYMODULE, namely how to I create “MYMODULE” and do I place the code mentioned on the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Following code can be applied to MYTHEME.theme and adds a different template suggestion for page (401/403/404). [See credit to RuslanP (comment #22)](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2363987)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_page_alter() to set 40x template suggestions.
 *
 * @param array $suggestions
 * @param array $variables
 */
function mytheme_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $path_args = explode('/', trim(\Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath(), '/'));
  $suggestions = theme_get_suggestions($path_args, 'page');
  $http_error_suggestions = [
    'system.401' => 'page__401',
    'system.403' => 'page__403',
    'system.404' => 'page__404',
  ];

  $route_name = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
  if (isset($http_error_suggestions[$route_name])) {
    $suggestions[] = $http_error_suggestions[$route_name];
  }
}
```